# Matlab GUI: How to display filename as String in statictextbox?

Tags: matlab

I write a simple GUI to plot datas. When I load a data with 'uigetfile' it will update the static text box with the message 'Data 1 loaded', that's okay but it can be better. Can I change it to the specific filename? Is there a way to display the filename as string in Matlab?

For example, I import the file 'Hello.txt' and the static textbox update it to 'Hello.txt loaded'

Here my code for the import button:

```
global geoh x1

[path, file] = uigetfile({'*.txt';'*.*'},'File Selector');

if isequal(file, 0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
   set(handles.text4,'String','No Data')
   return;
else
    set(handles.text4,'String','Data 1 loaded'); %this line is for the static textbox. 
end                                               
 a = dlmread(path);        
   x1 = a(:,5);
geoh = a(:,7);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that the function `uigetfile` returns `[file, path]` so, for clarity, you shoud change the call as follows

```
%[path, file] = uigetfile({'*.txt';'*.*'},'File Selector');

[file, path] = uigetfile({'*.txt';'*.*'},'File Selector');
```

Then to add the name of the file you have just to modify

```
set(handles.text4,'String','Data 1 loaded');
```

with

```
set(handles.text4,'String',[strcat(file, ' loaded')])
```

to display only the filename, or

```
set(handles.text4,'String',[strcat(path, '\', file, ' loaded')])
```

to display the full path and filename.

Hope this helps.